# SqlProfiler catch encrypted queries. Is it correct?

Tags: sql-server, ssl, profiler

I have `encrypt=true` in the connection string to MsSqlServer2008R2 database.
So as i understand the traffic between IIS and database has to be encrypted.
But when i open SQL profiler i see every query that comes from web server is unencrypted (Select from ... where ...)
Is it correct behavior ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. SSL only encrypts the network traffic, but SQL Profiler gets its information directly from the database engine. Have you reviewed the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649255.aspx) on enabling and testing encryption?